# Writing the needed or the known as clarification?

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

Suppose $\kappa > 2 \ $ and $a,b \ $ two positive real numbers satisfying $a > b$. If somewhere in a proof about $a, b \ $ I would need the inequality $a^{-\kappa} < b^{-\kappa}$, how should I write the argument?

Should I write

> Since $\kappa > 0 \ $ and $a > b \ $ we have $a^{-\kappa} < b^{-\kappa}$

or

> Since $\kappa > 2 \ $ and $a > b \ $ we have $a^{-\kappa} < b^{-\kappa}$?

It does not seem to be a huge difference, but I encountered this problem some times and want to be consequent and clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer:
Since $a>b>0$ it holds that $a^{-\gamma} < b^{-\gamma}$ for all $\gamma>0$, thus we have $a^{-\kappa} < b^{-\kappa}$.

It is also important here that $a, b$ are both positive (which you assumed).